# Insert Array field into mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

When i insert this type of array values directly into Mysql database, I got error like this

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':23:09Z, 36840bd430637, Success, 85.0, 11457922, 10.02, USD, X, M, 59106737WV831' at line 1

and myquery is

```
 INSERT INTO `transaction`(TIMESTAMP, CORRELATIONID, ACK, VERSION, BUILD, AMT, CURRENCYCODE, AVSCODE, CVV2MATCH, TRANSACTIONID) VALUES (2014-06-26T02:23:09Z, 36840bd430637, Success, 85.0, 11457922, 10.02, USD, X, M, 59106737WV831451U)
```

Mycode is

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($result_array));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($result_array));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `transaction`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
$res =mysql_query($sql);
```

what are the changes can i do?

Comment: First, get rid of the `echo` in `echo $sql...` then use quotes around your values. That should get you started ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should escape column names (not always required):

```
$cols = join(',', array_map(function($name) {
    return '`' . str_replace('`', '``', $name) . '`';
}, array_keys($result_array));
```

Then, keeping in mind that `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't add quoted enclosures:

```
$vals = join(',', array_map(function($value) {
    return "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
}, $result_array);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `transaction` ($cols) VALUES ($vals)";
```

Lastly, using `mysql_` functions is deprecated and you should move onto using either PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

What is meaning of echo $sql here? try this way  &  you can also escape your string firstly.

```
foreach($singleRow as $key=>$data) //for multiple rows
{
 if(isset($data)){
   $dataArray[$key] = is_string($data) ? mysql_real_escape_string($data) : $data;
   }
}

$tableName='transaction';
$keys = implode(',',array_keys($dataArray));
$data_values = ("'".implode("','",array_values($dataArray))."'");
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName." ($keys) VALUES ($data_values)";
$res =mysql_query($insertSql );

use mysqli_* and PDO anyway
```

Comment: Why did you throw away the `mysql_real_escape_string()`?